# EF Core does not Update Property of Type Base-Class

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

i'm using EF Core with TPH.

Let's say i have Base-Class called "BlogBase"

```
public class abstract BlogBase
{
   public int BlogId {get;set;}
}
```

and in addition i've two Classes which inherit from BlogBase

```
public class RssBlog : BlogBase
{
   public string Name {get;set;}
}

public class Blog : BlogBase
{
   public string Address {get;set;}
}
```

At least i've another Class which use Blog as a Property (FK)

```
public class Website
{
   public int WebsiteId {get;set;}
   public int BlogBaseId {get;set;}
   public virtual ICollection<BlogBase> Blog {get;set;}
}
```

The problem now is, that when i am try to change the "Blog" Property of a Website-Object, the value change (in-memory - the debugger shows the right value), but when i call SaveChanges it does not have any effect to the database. So at least the value does not get updated at the database.

```
website.Blog = new RssBlog();
```

or

```
website.Blog = new Blog();
```

Do you guys have any idea why it's not working?
There is no exception when i call SaveChanges().

Thanks!

Comment: mark Blog as virtual

Comment: @benuto still not working...

Comment: U also need a  BlogBaseId property as foreign key or use fluent api [ef core navigation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relationships?tabs=fluent-api%2Cfluent-api-simple-key%2Csimple-key)

Comment: thanks again. I've added the BlogBaseId and do still have the problem. Also I've forgot to tell, that I've a one-to-many-Relation. So Website do have a ICollection<BlogBase>